# How can I publicly share files in Evernote?

Tags: evernote, sharing

I've downloaded the desktop Evernote application and want to share a notebook online. Following this blog post I can't find the Action dropdown he's talking about. Any help?

http://blog.evernote.com/2008/04/21/publishing-sharing-your-notes/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you read the part at the very beginning of the post that says, "UPDATE: Things have changed quite a bit since this post. Please read our new Sharing and Collaboration post."?

If you haven't clicked that new Sharing and Collaboration link, do it - there are new instructions, and you need to do this in the web client, not the desktop client. The quick version? Log into your web account, click the blue Sharing tab on the left, then click Sharing Setup. Here's a screenshot:

[image]